# gets_s() в цикле съедает первый символ в строке

Tags: c++, c

Всем доброго времени суток. Вот такой вопрос:

```
cout << "Введите количество строк, которые хотите ввести -> ";
cin >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
            cout << "Введите строку -> ";
            cin.ignore();
            gets_s(str);
            pptr = ADDstr(pptr, sz, str);
            sz++;
    }
SHOWstr(pptr, sz);
```

Программка запрашивает строки у пользователя и потом выводит, после второй итерации цикла у строк пропадает первый символ, теряет его функция gets_s(), но побороть это у меня пока не вышло. Не подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Так вы же сами вызываете метод `cin.ignore()`, который отбрасывает первый символ из потока ввода.

Comment: Если cin.ignore() не вызывать, то gets_s() будет вовсе игнорироваться.  cin.ignore() отлавливает нажатие на enter, проблема в gets_s()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `gets_s` вызывается с двумя параметрами. Но это неважно, потому что, вообще говоря, порочен сам подход - смешивать С++ и С. Почему бы вам не воспользоваться соответствующими функциями [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)?

А если уж так хочется смеси французского с нижегородским - то `cin.ignore()` нужно вызвать один раз, сразу после `cin >> m;`.

Comment: К сожалению, нас в академии еще не учили как пользоваться классами вроде "string", так что буду мешать французский с нижегородским) Спасибо большое!

Comment: Вы по приведенной ссылке смотрели? Я специально дал вам ссылку на чтение в обычный строковый буфер! Практически полный аналог `gets_s`!

Comment: Только что попробовал, это то что мне нужно! `cin.ignore()` всё равно нужен на сколько я понял? Отличие только в том, что `cin.getline()` - это С++ функция, а `gets_s()` - C функция, правильно? Буду знать, спасибо :)

Comment: И еще получается что, в `gets_s()` можно передавать только имя массива, если у него уже задана размерность, а с `cin.getline()` такое не пройдёт

Comment: Вообще-то и в `gets_s` нужно передавать размер - см. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets Что касается `getline`, то в отличие от `gets_s` она работает не только со стандартным вводом, а с любым потоком. `ignore` нужен после `cin >> m;`, чтобы убрать из буфера ввода несчитанный `\n`